# Xamarin.iOS:FileNotFoundException with BundleResource files when targeting device

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

In an iOS application in Visual Studio, I have some text files in a subfolder under the Resources folder. They are marked "Build Action: BundleResource" and "Copy to output directory: Do not copy".

This works fine in the iOS simulator. But when targeting an iPad, when the app attempts to open these files for reading, it gets this error:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/var/containers/Bundle/Application/93C441FF-5D28-4A06-9C55-5CCA8A46D493/MyProjectName/MySubFolderName/MyFileName".

So I guess it's saying that the files are not being copied to that folder on the iPad. Does anyone have a suggestion as to what is wrong?

Comment: please show the code you are using to read the files

Comment: ModelFolder is constructed using `SBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath`. It resolves to the following...

Targetting the simulator...
/Users/BobC8/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/71F36125-CF6E-4DD1-BE93-11F6CB475F85/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/7BE788AC-84EA-4940-B6F7-A91E51BA6A67/CSApp.app/Model

--- Targetting the iPad...
/var/containers/Bundle/Application/D500AD01-1B4C-4FEE-9247-E2865A488E95/CSApp.app/Model

Then it opens a StreamReader -- this gives the error...

`string enginePath = Path.Combine(GFileAccess.ModelFolder, fName);`
`var rdr = new StreamReader(enginePath);`

Comment: to start with, I would try using a relative path "MySubFolderName/MyFileName".  It should use the root path of your app as the basis for any relative path.  Also be aware that the sim is NOT case sensitive but an actual device is

Comment: I *am* using a subfolder, "Model", which in VS is placed in the Resources folder. My understanding is that Xamarin will then place the subfolder directly under the root.

Comment: Ok -- The file names themselves were all lower case on disk but mixed in code. Thank you for the tip.